# Customer user | The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later. M2

Tags: magento2.3, customer-account

I get this error mostly on my local magento setup when I try to get customer token using default API. And usually it is with more than one customer accounts.

```
"message": "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.",
```

I checked customer Personal information from backend and there it is showing as:

> Account Lock: Unlocked

I tried to solve by upgrading db also flushed cache but no luck.

Comment: Have you found any solution?